# Event for SQLcommand finished

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

Is there an event that will tell me when a SQL query has finished.  I am populating a table view using the following code.

```
cmd = new SqlCommand(MainWindow.product.query, cliConnect);
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        sda.Fill(MainWindow.product.dt);
```

The reason I want to do this is because I want to have a waiting screen that has some animations playing while the user waits for there query.  Some of them could take up to a minute.

So I need the event to let me know when to switch to my next WPF page and populate a datagrid with the Data Table

Comment: That is synchronous code. You know when it has finished because you *get to the next line*.

Answer (score 0):

Use the BackgroundWorker class to get your data. It will fire off the RunWorkerCompleted event when it is done. While it is running, play your animation.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx